# what is the difference between how many years and how long years

Tags: grammar, questions

for example
1- how many years you lived in this house ?

or 
2- how long years you lived in this house ?

which one is right ?

Comment: First of all, sentence construction in both the sentences is wrong. Yo can say - For how many years have you lived in this house.

Comment: First of all, sentence construction in both the sentences is wrong. You can say - "For how many years have you lived in this house.?" . Secondly, in second sentence you you should not use 'years' if you have used the word 'long' - ''For how long have you lived in this house?"

Answer (score 4):

**Both are incorrect.**

The first could be salvaged by asking:

- How many years **have** you lived in this house?
- How many years **did** you live in this house?

The auxiliary verbs "have" and "did" are required to make it grammatical.  The first utterance assumes that the person receiving the question is still living in the house (the act of "living in the house" is on-going), while the second one assumes that the person  no longer lives there (the act of "living in the house" has ended.)

Similarly, the second utterance should be either:

- How long **have** you lived in this house?
- How long **did** you live in this house?

Again, the auxiliary verbs are needed to make this grammatical;  the distinction in meaning between the two is the same as above.  "How many" is a more general construction that asking about a quantity of something ("How many years?"  "How many apples?"  "How many people?"), and so needs to be followed by a (plural) noun;  whereas "how long" is only used to ask about quantities of time, and so doesn't need to be followed by a noun.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *How long years* is not grammatical, neither is it idiomatic in any context whatever. And it is a frequent error which some people learning English make.

***How many years have you worked for your present employer?*** is perfectly grammatical.

Equally you could say ***How long have you worked for...?***

The only way that the adjective *long* can qualify a time period is by saying something like *It has been a long day/month/year* etc.